# Read something from Azure SQL in Windows Phone Background Agent

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm writing Windows Phone 8 application and I've got problem with accessing my Azure Mobile Services database from Windows Phone 8 background agent.

I'm using that code:

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("https://name.azure-mobile.net/","secret!");
...
await ScheduledAgent
                 .MobileService
                 .GetTable<Element>()
                 .Where(e =>
                        e.First == parameters[1]
                        && e.Next == parameters[2]
                        && e.Other == parameters[3]
                        && e.Last == parameters[4])
                 .Take(1)
                 .ToListAsync());
```

And when I set breakpoint on line containing that code debugger stops, but after step over (F10) Visual Studio detaching debugger from Background Agent (app still working on emulator), so I can't catch an exception.

Is any possibility to access it from there?

Kind regards!

Comment: What kind of problem you have with the WP8 library for accessing Azure Mobile Services?

Comment: It is possible to use mobile service in background task. Describe your problem.

Comment: Just added some details.